# How to get info from certain row in a listview without clicking on the listview?

Tags: c#

I gather info from my db and I get them inside my listview successfully.
I gather them on my xaml.cs page and then I bind it to my xaml.

Now as I mentioned in my title I am now looking to get information from a certain row in my listview with for example a button.

As you will see in my code below I create an int called rowIndex that increases value in my foreach loop so all rows get a unique id. How can I now with for example a button get the connected info to that rowIndex, so if I with a button try to get the info from row 4 for example, how can I get the info on that row?

```
public class items
{
    public string name { get; set;}
    public int rowid { get; set;}
}

List<items> theList = new List<items>();

void loadVideo ()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    var getItems = await getData.MyInfo();
    foreach (var item in getItems)
    {
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
        theList.Add(new items
        {
           rowid = rowIndex,
           name = item ["thename"].ToString()
        }
    }

  listview.ItemsSource = theList;
}
```

And my binding:

```
 <Label Text = "{Binding name}" />
```

With the code above I get the name + rowIndex in my listview succesfully and each row has a unique number from 1-19 (i have 19 different names in my database).

And here is my separate button where I now try to get info from a particular row. So if I want the info from row 4. I want to get the connected "name".

```
void buttonClick (object s, EventArgs e)
{
 //so if I want info from row 4 in my listview, how would i accomplish this?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull the data from the ListView's ItemSource, not from the ListView itself.

```
void button4Click (object s, EventArgs e)
{
  var selectedName = theList[4].name;
}
```

Comment: Easier than I thought! Thanks